# C# doesn't create Unreachable code detected warning

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, null, compiler-warnings, primitive

C# seems to allow to compare between primatives (bool, int) to null.

```
bool a = true;
if (a != null)
{
     return null;
}
Console.Write("a");
```

Furthermore it doesn't generate
Warning:
Unreachable code detected
That you will get when changing a != null to true.

Changing a != null to true != null won't compile.

Is there an explanation for this behavior? Or is it a compiler bug?

Comment: I get a compile-time warning with Roslyn, btw. ("The result of the experssion is always false, since a value of type bool is never equal to null of type bool?"

Comment: @JonSkeet: And in VS2013 too (and VS2010).

Comment: I do get the warning with VS 2012 as "The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'bool' is never equal to 'null' of type 'bool?'"

Comment: this code wont compile in VS 2013.

Comment: VS 2013. (a != null) - warning: The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'bool' is never equal to 'null' of type 'bool?'
(true != null) - warning1: The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'bool' is never equal to 'null' of type '<null>'; warning2 - Unreachable code detected. Which version of VS you use?

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet I'm using VS2013. I'm getting "Warning:The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'bool' is never equal to 'null' of type 'bool?" So if it is True I should enter into return null thus Console.Write won't be reached...

Comment: @AmirKatz: Right, exactly. So as a *warning* it's appropriate - but the *reachability* rules of the language don't include anything for this, so the `Console.Write` call isn't classified as unreachable code.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'm still not sure why those 2 warnings are depended. Since if you change the a != null to true you will get the unreachable warning.. And in the current state you will get the always true warning.. But it is what it is I guess :) Thanks...

Comment: @AmirKatz: At that point, you've got a *constant expression*, and there are far more rules around that. This is something where the compiler is inferring information above and beyond what the language specification requires.